# Angular 2: Hide sidebar menu after clicking a particular page icon

Tags: angular

When the click action from HeaderComponent

[Heder Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhsu7.png)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="collapseSidebar()">
   <app-feather-icons id="sidebar-toggle" [icon]="'align-left'"></app-feather-icons>
</a>
```

```
  collapseSidebar() {
    this.navServices.collapseSidebar = !this.navServices.collapseSidebar
  }
```

```
export class NavService {

    public screenWidth: any
    public collapseSidebar: boolean = false;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,) {
        this.onResize();
        if (this.screenWidth < 991) {
            this.collapseSidebar = true
        }
    }
}
```

It's working fine

But when I tried page component, using same function but not work.

[Page Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHEGq.png)

```
  collapseSidebar() {
    this.navServices.collapseSidebar = !this.navServices.collapseSidebar
  }
```

Note: HeaderComponent and service inside of shared folder, I tried out this share folder component.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your operation is **asynchronous** or **angular's change detection** is not triggering because `collapseSidebar` is in service (not as a component's field).

You should use observables to provide communication between components from service.

For further understanding https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#observable-data